# Create a SQL Server Windows virtual machine with Azure CLI

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-sql-database, azure-virtual-machine, azure-cli

I have used this link in order to create a virtual machine all in power shell.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sql/quickstart-sql-vm-create-powershell

For some reason I need to get the job done with Azure CLI, is there any what to fully automate it in Azure CLI?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of an Azure CLI command that will explicitly install the SQL IaaS Extension.  One thing you can try is to build out the VM in the CLI then do an ARM Template Deployment to [Configure Automated Patching](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/101-vm-sql-existing-autopatching-update).  Automated Patching is supported in your virtual machine through the SQL Server IaaS Agent extension. This extension must be installed on the VM to be able to use this feature. When you enable Automated Patching on your virtual machine, the **extension will be automatically installed**.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

```
az vm create -n sql -g <resourcegroupname> --image MicrosoftSQLServer:SQL2017-WS2016:Standard:14.0.1000200 --location  EastUS2 --admin-username <username> --admin-password <password> --verbose
```

Comment: Thanks, Yet is not as exact, I was trying to sort out [ -Skus "SQLDEV" -Version "latest" -ProvisionVMAgent ] parameters and struggling to install the SQL IaaS Agent. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Oh you did not mention that on your original question, please take time to add that detail. To may knowledge, if you try az vm extension set --name SqlIaaSAgent you won't see the SQL server configuration in the settings tab of the VM. However with PowerShell works: Set-AzureRmVMSqlServerExtension -ResourceGroupName  -VMName  -name "SQLIaasExtension" -version "1.2" -Location

Comment: Will you be willing to use PowerShell instead of CLI. CLI is very limited.